# Why am I getting a 'No module named numpy' error when trying to import numpy in Python despite successfully installing it using pip?

Tags: python, numpy, pip

I'm working on a Python project that requires the use of the numpy library. However, when I try to import it, I get the following error: "No module named 'numpy'". I have already installed numpy using pip, so I'm not sure why this error is occurring. Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

1. I used the command `pip install numpy` to install numpy, and it was successfully installed.
2. I verified the installation by running `pip show numpy`, which showed the correct version and installation location.
3. I restarted my Python interpreter and tried importing numpy again, but the error persists.

Comment: Check if you installed it for the right Python `--version` of you have multiple installed.

Comment: If you have multiple versions of python on your computer, pip might be on one version of python while you are using a different version of python. Always type `python -m pip install` to make sure you're using the pip that is attached to the correct python version.